# Broken $PATH variable

Tags: macos, terminal

I was trying to add something to my $PATH variable, but I think I made some sort of typo.

Now, I am trying to fix this, I want to remove what I added, but when I type e.g. `open .profile`, it tells me `-bash: open: command not found`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the full path to open:

```
/usr/bin/open .profile
```

Once you've fixed your path, your shell will be functional again.